# how to 'dim' certain python statements in PyCharm

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting, pycharm

PyCharm version: Community Edition 4.0.4

Is it possible to customize my color scheme for a python file in PyCharm such that certain statements are of darker color?

e.g. I want to make all statements starting with "logger" to be of gray color so that I can focus on my main code without having to wade through lot of info/debug statements.

I tried to find out if I can add new keyword in `keywords1 keywords2 keywords3 keywords4` but can't find any such option. And on top of that, I can't find any way to alter colors for keyword1/2/3/4 individually.

I can't be the only one wanting to hide/dim logging statements!

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature in PyCharm 4.